# T-sql update value based on sub select result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, sql-update

MS SQL 2008 in use and stored procedure is needed.

So in my table i have certain rows where IsDouble value will be 2. 
Now i need to update IsDouble from 2 to 1 for each line from the first select if a count of string (concatenated from 4 columns) is greater than 1 and if the count of the string is 1 to 0

So far i have this but it's most likely incorrect:

```
select * from TestInvoiceData where Isdouble='2';
update TestInvoiceData
set testinvoicedata.Isdouble=
case 
    when  
    (
        select COUNT (InvoiceDate+InvoiceNumber+VendorCode+Invoicetype) 
        from      TestInvoiceData
     ) >1 then 1
     else 0
end;
```

EDIT

Here's the sample data (invoicetype,invoicenumber,invoicedate,vendorcode):

```
INVO    322760-262  2012-05-10  0000081964  2
INVO    322760-262  2012-05-10  0000081964  0
INVO    322756-262  2012-05-10  0000081964  2
INVO    7011200072  2012-05-10  0000046172  0
INVO    7011200071  2012-05-10  0000046172  0
INVO    7011200070  2012-05-10  0000046172  0
INVO    7011200069  2012-05-10  0000046172  0
INVO    7011200068  2012-05-10  0000046172  0
INVO    12106563    2012-04-24  0000010171  0
INVO    06649       2012-04-24  0000067987  0
```

and based on this example the first row should be after update 1 and the third one 0

Comment: you need to give sample data... with such query

Comment: You're naming a column `Isdouble` which is not a `bool/bit`?

Comment: it is not bool/bit, it's nchar, i will add sample data

Comment: you can use `WHERE` in update statement itself

Comment: here's the sample data:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXAmple](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1ced/2)**

```
UPDATE TestInvoiceData
SET Isdouble = (
SELECT   CASE WHEN count(*)>1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END AS cnt
FROM TestInvoiceData t1
  WHERE t1.invoicetype =TestInvoiceData.invoicetype 
  AND   t1.invoicenumber = TestInvoiceData.invoicenumber
  AND   t1.invoicedate = TestInvoiceData.invoicedate
  AND   t1.vendorcode = TestInvoiceData.vendorcode
GROUP BY t1.invoicetype,
         t1.invoicenumber,
         t1.invoicedate,
         t1.vendorcode)
WHERE Isdouble = '2'
```

Result:

```
| INVOICETYPE | INVOICENUMBER |                  INVOICEDATE | VENDORCODE | ISDOUBLE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        INVO |    322760-262 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      81964 |        1 |
|        INVO |    322760-262 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      81964 |        0 |
|        INVO |    322756-262 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      81964 |        0 |
|        INVO |    7011200072 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      46172 |        0 |
|        INVO |    7011200071 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      46172 |        0 |
|        INVO |    7011200070 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      46172 |        0 |
|        INVO |    7011200069 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      46172 |        0 |
|        INVO |    7011200068 |   May, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      46172 |        0 |
|        INVO |      12106563 | April, 24 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      10171 |        0 |
|        INVO |         06649 | April, 24 2012 00:00:00+0000 |      67987 |        0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need

```
update TestInvoiceData set

Isdouble=CASE 
            WHEN (select count(*) from TestInvoiceData as Tid
                  where 
                  tId.InvoiceDate=InvoiceDate
                  AND
                  tId.InvoiceNumber=InvoiceNumber
                  AND
                  tId.VendorCode=VendorCode
                  AND
                  tId.Invoicetype =Invoicetype 
                 ) > 1
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END

where Isdouble=2
```